# Edge extension to rename tab title not working

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to write an Edge extension that changes the title of a tab.

Here is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to change the tab's title.
When I add alert(tab.title) it does seem like it has changed.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Tab",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Microsoft Edge Extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "author": "abc",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "bg.html",     
     
      "default_title": "Hello World"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>"
  ],   
  "background": {
  "page": "bg.html",
  "persistent": true
}
}
```

**bg.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Click the button to get the page URL...<h3><br>
        <button id="btn1">click me</button>
        <input type="text" id="txt1" style="width:300px">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
var btn= document.getElementById("btn1");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  abc();
});

function abc()
{
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
    {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            var title = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            tabs[0].title = title;
            tab.reload();
    });
}

Any idea?
```

Comment: Another approach I tried is this but it does not change the tab's title, only the html.
let title = prompt("Title");
document.title = title;

Comment: Hi @Blondy314, have you tried my solution? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I change the tab's title. It involves a content script. Also, I used `sendMessage` in `background.js` to pass the title into content script. Don't forget to add the content script to your `manifest.json`.

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.title)
    {
        document.title = request.title;
    }
})
```

**background.js**

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  abc();
});

function abc()
{
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
    {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            var title = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {title: title}, function(response){});
    });  
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "My Tab",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "Simple Microsoft Edge Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "author": "abc",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "bg.html", 
    "default_title": "Hello World"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {    
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],   
    "background": {
    "page": "bg.html",
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```